# How to add or replace a custom object in an ArrayList using Java 8 functionality most efficiently?

Tags: java, arraylist, replace, java-stream

How can I replace a custom object in an ArrayList using Java 8 if a particular property of that custom object equals the property of the object to be added?
If the Arraylist is empty, the new object shall be added. 
If the ArrayList contains elements I want to find out if an element exists with the same name and if so it shall be replaced by the new one, if no element has the name of the new element it should be added to the ArrayList.

```
public class MyElement {
    private String name;
    private String value;
}

public class MyElementList {
    private List<MyElement> elements;

    public void add(final MyElement newElement) {
        // By using Java 8 functionality (streams)...
        // add if elements is empty or if newElement is not existent in elements
        // replace oldElement in elements if oldElement.getName().equals(newElement.getName())
    }
}
```

`MyElementList` shall be transformed to JSON later on so that one JSON node looks like:

```
{[
    {
        "name" : "xxx",
        "value" : "yyy"
    },
    {
        "name" : "zzz",
        "value" : "111"
    }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Why not go with a `Map<String, MyElement>` instead? Keep the name as the key, and you don't need to touch streams or process the whole list every time. In fact, then your method would just be `map.put(newElement.getName(), newElement);`.

Comment: If you replace an existing element with a new one, should the new one be placed in the same position as the existing element?

Comment: The position is not important. It's also sufficient to delete the old one and add the new one.

Comment: @du-it then the map based solution is even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `removeIf` to remove the old element (based on the condition) and then add the new element (regardless of whether or not the old element was removed):

```
elements.removeIf(e -> e.getName().equals(newElement.getName()));
elements.add(newElement);
```

Comment: this solution add the element at the end of list, I need to replace at the same index of old one

Answer (score 0):

Think about using the *java.util.Set* interface which is a *Collection* without duplicate elements (based on the *equals* method of the objects).

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList accept duplicates so you may consider using another Collection  **Set** Or just delete the old one and then add the new one

```
    public class MyElement {
       private String name;
       private String value;

       //Add equals by name
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
         if (this == obj) {
          return true;
         }
         if (obj == null) {
          return false;
         }
         if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
          return false;
         }
         final MyElement other = (MyElement) obj;
         if (!Objects.equals(this.name, other.name)) {
         return false;
        }
        return true;
       }


   }

   class MyElementList {
       private List<MyElement> elements;

       public void add(final MyElement newElement) {
         //del Old
         elements.remove(newElement);
         //Add new
         elements.add(newElement);
       }
    }
```